# How to generate fiducial markers for BoofCV?

Tags: java, processing, boofcv

I'm wanting to use [BoofCV with Processing](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Tutorial_Processing), but its recognition of any size of ArUco markers generated by [this tool](http://chev.me/arucogen/) is unstable. Is there a resource or an app where I can get or generate a collection of markers that will be consistently recognized by BoofCV in Processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BoofCV doesn't work with Aruco Markers, yet at least. It's been on the wish list for a while now since everything needed to process Aruco Markers is there but it doesn't support their dictionaries.

https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Tutorial_Fiducials

Instructions for creating BoofCV markers is there. Basically you can use a command line tool for creating PDFs. There might even be a GUI, I can't remember, but it's not difficult.